# Why is my the front of the book cover warping into its back?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a book that I created with transitions. Its created using 3 divs, one for the back with a class of back and two for the front. The first div for the front is for the front of the cover and other for the back of the cover. When you hover over the book the front flips open showing the div with a class of back and the back of the cover.

The issue is for a second the front of the cover, which is a blue div shows through to the back as its opening and closing-why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

```css
*{
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
.book{
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 300px;
  perspective-origin: right bottom;
}
.book:hover .front{
    transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}
.book .front{
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: left;
  background-color: blue;
}
.book,.front,.front-front,.front-back,.back{
  width: 130px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front-front{
   z-index:1;
   background-color: blue;
}
.back{
  z-index: -1;
}
.front-front,.front-back,.front{

}
.front-front,.front-back,.back,.front{
  position: absolute;
}
.front-back{
  transform: rotatey(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
  <div class="front">
    <div class="front-front">
    front
    </div>
    <div class="front-back">
    back
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
  back of book
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `backface-visibility: hidden;` to your rules for `.book,.front,.front-front,.front-back,.back{`

Comment: You can re add solution